# intellij not picking up inherited class annotation using spring

Tags: spring, annotations, intellij-idea

I have BaseUnitTest, it looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseInitUser {
```

My actual test classes extend this and everything works fine. Except intellij is highlighting an error on bean injection, even though it actually works :
[image]

But when I add the annoation specifying context config to subclass the error disapears :

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class RegistrationControllerTest extends BaseInitUser {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84470). Star/vote in YouTrack to receive notifications on progress.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the contextConfig annotation to reference "classpath:myFile.xml" and it now works as expected (as mentioned in bug report)